# AsyncWebsocketConsumer VS AsyncConsumer

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to use `Channels2` in my project. it's the first time that I meet channel in Django :)
I have two main useful and almost complete sources here: 1)video on youtube [DJANGO CHANNELS 2 Tutorial (V2) - Real Time](http://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVH05S1qab8) 2)document of Channel in [Read The Doc](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

as I don't know what will happen in the future of my code I need you to help me choose using between `AsyncConsumer` as mentioned in source #1, or `AsyncWebsocketConsumer` that is used in source # 2 for starting `Django channel app` that including by this way:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer
```

explanation:

```
class AsyncConsumer:
    """
    Base consumer class. Implements the ASGI application spec, and adds on
    channel layer management and routing of events to named methods based
    on their type.
    """

class AsyncWebsocketConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    """
    Base WebSocket consumer, async version. Provides a general encapsulation
    for the WebSocket handling model that other applications can build on.
    """
```

my goal of using channel: trying to integrated real-time chat, notification/alert/transfer_data to the clients for the specific situations. (now the app working without Websocket with DRF)

and if you have any suggestions, ideas or notices I will be very happy to listen.thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Channels is a project meant to be used to work with different protocols including but not limited to HTTP and WebSockets as explained on the [docs page](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).
The `AsyncConsumer` is the base generic consumer class from which other protocol-specific consumer classes are derived. One of those classes is the `AsynWebsocketConsumer` which you mentioned. As the name goes, it's used to work with websockets, so if you want use websockets for your realtime app, then that is the class you should use. There is also the [AsyncHttpConsumer](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html#asynchttpconsumer) for working with HTTP. You most likely want to work with websockets so go with the `AsynWebsocketConsumer` or its derivative, `AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer`.

I would also advise that you read the documentation to understand in better detail about the supported protocols and how and when to use them.